# Not using BULK but still getting ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: Bulk Bind: Truncated Bind

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following statement results in this error message:

`ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: Bulk Bind: Truncated Bind`

```
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (SELECT
                  COALESCE (
                            (SELECT '123' FROM dual WHERE  1=0) ,
                            (SELECT '123' || '4' FROM dual)
                           )
                          FROM DUAL
              )
   LOOP
        NULL;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

There is obviously no bulk statement involved in any way.

When I change the first `123` to `1234` the error goes away. It seems the COALESCE in the cursor is messing up the allocated string space?

This happens with my Oracle 12.2.0.1 but also with Oracle 18 in https://livesql.oracle.com/ (needs registration)

Is this an Oracle bug or am I overlooking something.

**Update**

I have created a Service Request with Oracle. They can reproduce the problem and are investigating.

Comment: What do you get when you run just the select?

Comment: Just the SELECT runs fine and returns the '1234'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NVL2` instead of `COALESCE`

```
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (SELECT
                  NVL2 (
                            (SELECT '123' FROM dual WHERE  1=0) ,
                            (SELECT '123' || '4' FROM dual), null
                           )
                          FROM DUAL
              )
   LOOP
        NULL;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Edit**  For the root cause of the problem

First of all, `Coalesce` need both arguments to be in same data type. Also, data types of expressions are determined in order.

In your case, It seems that your first query is three characters long `SELECT '123' FROM dual WHERE  1=0)` and the second one is 4 characters long with concatenation (concatenation has role here: i am trying to sort that out as well). Hence, oracle tries to convert `varchar2(4)` data type (second statement) to `varchar2(3)` data type (first Statement). Thus, ORA-6502 occurs

Comment: I think you mean to use NVL instead of NVL2?  
That seems indeed to work better but it still is strange that the SELECT by itself does not given any error.

Comment: I tried many variations of it and only this gives error and I am sure that It is about character scales and string concatenation. Anyway hope that It helped you. Also if you believe that this answer helped you, please consider to upvote / mark it as answer. Regards

Answer (score -1):

Sort of looks like because the first select would result in a NO_DATA_FOUND rather than a true NULL then it causes COALESCE to not work, however NVL will handle it so that is a bit strange.

One way round it is to wrap the select in a NVL as per the below...

```
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (SELECT
                  NVL2 (
                            (NVL((SELECT '123' FROM dual WHERE  1=0), null)) ,
                            (SELECT '123' || '4' FROM dual), null
                           )
                          FROM DUAL
              )
   LOOP
        NULL;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```